# How to draw an arc greater than 180 deg in tikz-3dplot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

`\tdplotdrawarc` command draws an inferior arc by default, but how to draw an superior arc?

I know that there is a way to draw an superior arc in `tikz`:

```
\tikz \draw (0,0) arc [start angle=0, end angle=315, x radius=1.75cm, y radius=1cm];
```

But l parameters of a command? The manual seems isn't detailed enough.how to do it in `tikz-3dplot`?

By the way, where can I find description of all parameters of a command? The manual seems isn't detailed enough.

---

Solution found.

Just let `Abs(end angle - start angle) > 180deg`.

Like this:

```
\tdplotdrawarc[thick,-{Latex}] {(4.5,0,-0.5)} {0.5} {320} {-20} {anchor=north} {$T_1$}
```

Comment: The arc command doesn't change.  One uses \tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{angle} to rotate the x,y plane.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks a lot, but I wanted to specify the center of arc so `\tdplotdrawarc` satisfied my need. Any idea how to specify the center of arc in `\draw arc`?

Comment: In 2D, its just \draw (x,y) arc[start angle, end angle, radius=r];  In 3D you might need to \begin{scope}{xshift=x,yshift=y]

Comment: @RuoxiWang: We'd like to keep answers separate from questions, so you should write a separate answer instead of editing your answer into the question. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

Comment: @Ruoxi Wang : Just an reminder. Could you add your answer (separatly) and [accept](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) your [own answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)? It's perfectly okay to ask and answer your own question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution found.

Just let `Abs(end angle - start angle) > 180deg`.

Like this:

```
\tdplotdrawarc[thick,-{Latex}] {(4.5,0,-0.5)} {0.5} {320} {-20} {anchor=north} {$T_1$}
```